# How to test Comparator for JUnit test?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, junit, comparator

I need to test the compare() method and i am confused on how. Can I see how to do this?

```
public class MemberComparator implements Comparator<Member> {

    private final String clientId;

    public MemberComparator(String clientId) {
        this.clientId = clientId;
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(Member m1, Member m2) {
        if (m1.getClientId().startsWith(clientId)) {
            return m2.getClientId().startsWith(clientId) ? m1.getClientId().compareTo(m2.getClientId())
                    : -1;
        } else {
            return m2.getClientId().startsWith(clientId) ? 1
                    : m1.getClientId().compareTo(m2.getClientId());
        }
    }

}
```

So far, this is what i have created in my test. How can i get this to work? What should i do as this way isn't working, assuming i do not change the current approach to MemberComparator class.

```
class MemberComparatorTest {

//private MemberComparator caseID_test;
//private final MemberComparator memberComparator = new MemberComparator("jake");

@Test
void testEqual() {
    Member m1 = new Member();
    Member m2 = new Member();
    int result = memberComparator.compare(m1,m2);
    //assertTrue("expected to be equal", result == 0);

}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two questions you'd need to answer when writing a `Comparator`:

1. Does it meet the requirements of the `Comparator` interface?
2. Does it do what you need?

The first one is reasonably hard to write tests for; I'd argue it's better to write something using a "known good" pattern, in order to help you reason about its correctness from the code.

In the case of `Comparator`, the "known good" pattern is something that you see from the chaining methods:

```
// This boolean comparison may be the wrong way round, I never remember which way is which. If so, reverse it.
Comparator.comparing(m -> m.getClientId().startsWith(clientId))
    .thenComparing(Member::getClientId)
```

You compare the first thing, and return if they're different; you compare the second thing, and return if they're different, etc.

You could use the code above if you're using Java 8+: this gives a totally fine `Comparator`. If you can't use this (for whatever reason), your `compare` method could be rewritten as:

```
int compareSw = Boolean.compare(m1.getClientId().startsWith(clientId), m2.getClientId().startsWith(clientId));
if (compareSw != 0) {
  return compareSw;
}
return m1.getClientId().compareTo(m2.getClientId());
```

Because this follows the "known good" pattern, this can be seen to meet the requirements of the `Comparator` interface by inspection.

(Of course, you have to be careful about thinking "Looks Good To Me!", because you might miss something, e.g. using `m1.getClientId()` twice instead of both `m1.getClientId()` and `m2.getClientId()`. But that sort of defect would be caught by sufficient testing of the following).

Then it's just a matter of testing to make sure it does *what you want*: that is, if you take two `Member`s, does this `Comparator` order them the way you want? That's an easy test to write, without getting bogged down in the details of the `Comparator`.

```
List<Member> members = List.of(m1, m2);
assertEquals(m1, Collections.min(members, comparator));  // For example.
assertEquals(m2, Collections.max(members, comparator));  // For example.
```

Comment: How about if i do not change the MemberComparator class? How would i go about testing from then?

Answer (score 0):

Some assertions might look like:

```
assertTrue(comparator.compare(m1, m1) == 0);
assertTrue(comparator.compare(m1, m2) > 0);
assertTrue(comparator.compare(m2, m1) < 0);
```